# How can i get excel chart config by ChartObject that belongs to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Here is an excel file with one worksheet in it,also with some data in the worksheet.
Then the user create a chart,just like 'xlLine' or 'xlColumnClustered',and set some config info such as chart title,CategoryTitle,ValueTitle and so on.
And how can i get the config info,especially the selected data area of the chart?
Ths!

[the worksheet and chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaRdZ.png)

[some code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zycH.png)

```
        //Get the current worksheet
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet);
        //Get ChartObjects 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects objs = (ChartObjects)worksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        //Just get the first ChartObject
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject obj = objs.Item(1);
        //Get the chartTitle
        string chartTitle = obj.Chart.ChartTitle.Caption;
```

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of an image.